# How to parese a String in objective-c

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, xcode, parsing

i want to parse a string for replacing some elements.
if my string contains an `<ol>` then i want to parse for the `<li>` elements to replace them with numbers.

I know that i can check with `rangeOfString` for the containing String.

```
if ([myString rangeOfString:@"<ol>"].location != NSNotFound) {
    //Do stuff here  
}
```

**How can i parse only between `<ol>` and `</ol>` elements?**

**EDIT 1:** Here is my solution

```
- (NSString *)parseOrderedList:(NSString *)str {


NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[str length]];

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
NSString *tempText = nil;

while (![scanner isAtEnd])
{
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"<ol>" intoString:&tempText];
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"</ol>" intoString:&tempText];


    if (tempText != nil) {
        [html appendString:tempText];
        html = [[[html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</li>" withString:@" "] mutableCopy] autorelease];

            while ([html rangeOfString:@"<li>"].location != NSNotFound) {
                html = [[[html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<li>" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.", i]] mutableCopy] autorelease];
                i++;
            }

    }


    if (![scanner isAtEnd])
        [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation] + 0];

    tempText = @" ";

}

return html;
}
```

But how can i replace the

with the current count of loop? i am getting everytime the first count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
NSString * aString = @"your string";
NSMutableArray *substrings = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:aString];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"<ol>" intoString:nil]; // Scan all characters before <ol>
while(![scanner isAtEnd]) 
{
  NSString *substring = nil;
  [scanner scanString:@"<ol>" intoString:nil]; // Scan the <ol> character
  if([scanner scanUpToString:@"</ol>" intoString:&substring]) 
  {
  // If the space immediately followed the <ol>, this will be skipped
  [substrings addObject:substring];
  }
 [scanner scanUpToString:@"<ol>" intoString:nil]; // Scan all characters before next <ol>
}
```

U have string in nsmutablearray which can used to replace by your string

Same method can be repeated for other tags

Comment: Thank you, i have write a function to search for string between `<ol>` and `</ol>`. Now i try to replace all `<li>`with current count of loop, but still getting the first count as return. see my edited question.